# Changing password in ASP.Net Identity OAuth2 NOT working

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, oauth, change-password

I'm using  ASP.Net Identity OAuth2 as Back-end and Angular JS as Front-end. 
The problem is when I change my password from profile it works fine, but when I logged out and log in again, the new password DO NOT work and old password is the valid password so.

Also when I recover the password, the problem is still... :(

What can i do with that?

I can mention it that when I build and run project after changing or recovery the new password will work without any doubt... -_-

PS: Every request makes new access_token.

Comment: Please post your detail code.

Comment: @KhalidHussain i used the example of [this link](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

Comment: @KhalidHussain did you see the link?